# Find all unique file owners through Powershell in an NTFS file system

Tags: performance, powershell

I'm trying to find all unique file owners in an NTFS file system. Getting the number is fairly straightforward, but my current approac is very inefficient:

```
$Shares = @(
    "\\Server\Share1",
    "\\Server\Share2",
    "\\Server\Share3",
    "\\Server2\Share1",
    ...
)
$i = 0
foreach ($Share in $Shares) {
    $i++
    $AllFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $Share -File -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $Output = $AllFiles | ForEach-Object { [System.IO.FileSystemAclExtensions]::GetAccessControl($_).Owner } | Group-Object | Sort-Object Name | Select-Object Count, Name
    $Output | Out-File "C:\My Path\My file$i.csv"
}
```

I don't think there's any way around using `[System.IO.FileSystemAclExtensions]::GetAccessControl()` but is there some better, more efficient way of getting the unique file owners only? There are two issues I can see here:

1. Storing the file info of *every single file in the share* in a single variable
2. Running a `Group-Object` command on that massive data set

I thought about instead of using `Group-Object` storing them in a separate `ArrayList` and for each file see if the owner already exists but then I'd have to compare an increasingly large `ArrayList` with a value every time, so that feels like it would be exponentially slower than doing the `Group-Object` approach.

Are there better options doing this?

Answer (score 4):

If you only care about the unique file owners (not the count), something like (not fully fleshed out but to give you an idea):

```
function Get-UniqueOwners([String]$Path) {
  $GciArgs = @{ LiteralPath=$Path; Recurse=$True; Force=$True; ErrorAction='SilentlyContinue'; }
  $Owners = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[String]
  foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem @GciArgs | Where-Object {! $_.PSIsContainer}) {
    #"File: '{0}'" -f $file.FullName
    [void]$Owners.Add($file.GetAccessControl().Owner)
  }
  $Owners
}

$Shares = @(
    "\\Server\Share1",
    "\\Server\Share2",
)

foreach ($Share in $Shares) {
  "Scanning '{0}'" -f $Share
  Get-UniqueOwners $Share
  ""
}
```

Edit: or to get the owner count

```
function Get-OwnerCount([String]$Path) {
  $GciArgs = @{ LiteralPath=$Path; Recurse=$True; Force=$True; ErrorAction='SilentlyContinue'; }
  $Owners = @{}
  foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem @GciArgs | Where-Object {! $_.PSIsContainer}) {
    $Owners[$file.GetAccessControl().Owner]++
  }
  $Owners
}
```

Comment: I tried this back and forth but unfortunately I can't see any performance difference between using the Group-Object approach and this :( I assume that this is because the vast majority of the time is spent reading the owner information with .GetAccessControl() and that the time saving from Group-Object is comparatively negligeble. Although I do admit I haven't tried this in production yet so it could still be the case that this approach is somewhat faster should the Group-Object start taking hours. I will update when I have verified this!